# Undeterred by / from

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

The literature says that undeterred is followed by a *by*:

> A person is undeterred **by** a factor.

However, is it also possible to say:

> A person is undeterred **from** a factor.

?

Comment: It's possible to use many prepositions, but don't expect them all to mean the same thing. Please explain what you want.

Comment: @StuartF If a person is not deterred by something, the person is undeterred by it. But does the preposition "from" also work in this context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you aware of our sister site English Language Learners?  Questions about English preposition usage of this type may be appropriate there. They are not in my opinion appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

You're undeterred ***by*** a "deterrent" (something that might feasibly have stopped you ***from** doing what you want to do*).

Hence, you're undeterred ***from** doing what you want to do* - but note that this usage is [much less common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20undeterred%20by%2Cwas%20undeterred%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)